# DI^ как создать объект с параметром из настроек

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

Есть некий загрузчик web-страниц, который параметризуется типом загружаемой страницы. В зависимости от типа страницы нужно передавать адрес, с которого производить загрузку.

```
public class ExtraInfoPageLoader<T, DT> where T : class, IRootDto<DT>
{
    private readonly string _url;
    private readonly ILogger<ExtraInfoPageLoader<T, DT>> _logger;

    public ExtraInfoPageLoader(ILogger<ExtraInfoPageLoader<T, DT>> logger, string url)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _url = url;
    }

    public T LoadPage() 
    {
        // загрузка JSON-представления страницы и преобразование в тип T.
    }
}
```

Url для всех типов загрузчиков хранятся в файле appsetings.json
Собственно, вопрос, как добавить такой объект в services в методе ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services), чтобы он брал нужный url из appsettings?

Comment: [Configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), [Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: какой тип приложения?

Comment: @aepot. WebAPI. А какое это имеет значение?

Comment: Передавайте не url, а некий urlProvider, в котором реализуйте нужную логику получения url